# Looking for a way to add more information to Gatling transactions in the simulation.log file

Tags: logging, gatling, elk

Our team is currently attempting to integrate Gatling into our performance test tracking application. We have JMeter integrated already, and are now attempting to send all the same types of data from Gatling into our ELK stack.

The problem we're running into is that Gatling's simulation.log file that we intend to upload into Elasticsearch is missing a lot of the same data JMeter provides such as response code, url that was tested, bytes sent, etc.

I have attempted to configure the logback.xml file, however, doing so only seems to log the information in the CLI, and not in the simulation.log, and is missing a lot of the data anyway. Does anyone know of a way to specify what needs to be recorded in the simulation.log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulation.log file is an internal, not a public API. Format is subject to (and does) change without prior notice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In that case, is there a way to capture particular snapshots of information on our own, or does that mean what we get is what we get?

Comment: The former, there's not. Please note that FrontLine, the Enterprise version, has more metrics, such as responses broken down by HTTP status, connections and TLS metrics, etc.